# Derived category of a exact categories with (unusual) weak equivalences

Tags: derived-categories, algebraic-k-theory, infinity-categories

Every exact category $\mathcal{E}$ has an attached derived category (for simplicity I will just refer to the bounded one) $D^b(\mathcal{E})$.
The construction is for example explained in

1. A. Neeman, The derived category of an exact category, Journ. of Algebra 135.
2. B. Keller, Derived categories and their uses, Handbook of Algebra vol.1, p.671-701.
3. T. Bühler, Exact categories, Expositiones Math. 28

These constructions are really hands-on and immediate.

What can I do when I work with an exact category ***with weak equivalences*** instead?   This is a sort of amalgamation of the concepts of an exact category and its attached Waldhausen category. It occurs for example in the work of Grayson on binary complexes, or differently could be understood as a particularly nice special case of a Waldhausen category.

Sure enough, I can always set up the derived category by just brutally inverting the weak equivalences (the "relative category" approach), or I could first do a simplicial localization/Dwyer-Kan hammock localization, passing through a simplicial category, and then take its homotopy category.

However, these are fairly inaccessible to actual computations. For abelian categories or exact categories (where the weak equivalences are just isomorphisms) the derived category can be built with a very concrete calculus of fractions (in the Gabriel-Zisman sense). For example, computing Hom-groups in these categories is a very explicit problem, sometimes easy to tackle.

**Concrete Question** I am looking for literature which discusses criteria for exact categories with weak equivalences (or perhaps general Waldhausen categories) which ensures the existence of Gabriel-Zisman calculus of left/right fractions for $D^b(\mathcal{E},w)$ resp. $w^{-1}\mathcal{E}$.
Perhaps, one should better work with $(wq)^{-1}C^b(\mathcal{E})$ (forgive me for using the vague suggestive notation $wq$ for something like a family of weak equivalences generated by a choice of weak equivalences for $\mathcal{E}$ and quasi-isos)

Comment: Are you aware of the philosophy of cotorsion theories? See: Gillespie, J.:  Model structures on exact categories. *J. Pure Appl. Algebra*, **215** (2011), no. 12, 2892-2902, and the papers that refer to it.